# Azure "MySQL in App" An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: azure-mysql-database

I activated “MySQL in app” on Azure and clicked the “Manage” link. A phpMyAdmin login page launches.
Login does not accept any username/password combo including what I find in MYSQLCONNECTSTR_localdb.ini.
Is there any other setup required to access the tool, or is there another tool I could use to create a new db on MySQL in App?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. If the website has been stopped and restarted you have to first connect to the website URL from a browser.
Once you do that, the instance is running and you can connect to phpMyAdmin.
It will launch without a login screen.